# CSRF token validation failed in nodejs while posting data to odata service

Tags: node.js, post, odata, token, csrf

```
var request = require('request');
var username = '';
var password = '';
var url = 'http://207.188.73.88:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZTEE_TIME_SRV/ZTEERESERVESet(Time=time\'PT11H00M00S\',Date=datetime\'2014-03-11T00%3A00%3A00\',Location=\'TAJ\',Number=3)';
var auth = 'Basic ' + new Buffer(username + ':' + password).toString('base64');

// i am trying to post data to odata service but the problem is that i could not get valid token from get service to use it in the post method i am first send get method

request(
  {
    url: url,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': auth,
      'x-csrf-token': 'Fetch',
    },
  },
  function(error, response, body) {
    console.log('JSON data ' + response);
    console.log('body' + body);
    // trying to get the token to use in post
    console.log(response.headers);

    request(
      {
        url: url,
        headers: {
          here it says invalid token
          'Authorization': auth,
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': 'u6piLO58XoK6udOkQ5Naww==',
        },
        method: 'POST',
        //Lets post the following key/values as form
        form: {
          Time: 'PT11H00M00S',
          Date: '2014-03-11T00%3A00%3A00',
          Location: 'TAJ',
          Number: 3,
        },
      },
      function(error, response, body) {
        console.log(body);
      },
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: no i did not get the solution sorry for late response @mikel

Comment: Dont worry i found it, check the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution.

I was trying to do this with POSTMAN, and it was working fine. 
The thing is that when i was asking for CSRF token it always gave me the same back.
But when i tried with node, every time was different. Then i realized that the cookie was missing.

And thats all, the solution is to send the `cookie` at least in `POST` requests.

The `set-cookie` of the `"Fetch"` request must be sent in the `Post` request as `Cookie` beside the `x-csrf-token`

I put the example in typescript, but in js doesnt change so much, the idea is the same.

The example is not the best case but is complete to figure out how it works

```
let headers = {
  "Authorization": "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64"),
  "Content-Type":"application/json",
  "Accept":"application/json",
  "x-csrf-token":"Fetch" // get CSRF Token for post or update
};
// if you are using session vars
if (req.session.headers && req.session.headers.cookie) {
  headers['Cookie'] = req.session.headers.cookie;
} else {
  req.session.headers = {}; // initialize as object
}
let opts = {
  url: "https://{host}:{port}/sap/opu/odata/sap/MD_SUPPLIER_MASTER_SRV",
  qs: params1, // params set before, not set in the example
  headers: headers,
  json: true, 
}
request(opts, (error: any, response: any, body: any): any => {
  if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
    if (response.headers["set-cookie"]) { 
      req.session.headers.cookie = response.headers["set-cookie"]; // store Cookie in session
      headers['Cookie'] = req.session.headers.cookie; // set in headers for the next call. I guess this is the part you missed
    }
    if (response.headers['x-csrf-token']) {
      req.session.headers.csrf = response.headers['x-csrf-token']; // store csrf-token in session
      headers['x-csrf-token'] = req.session.headers.csrf; // set in headers for the next call
    }

    let options: request.Options = {
      url: "https://{host}:{port}/sap/opu/odata/sap/MD_SUPPLIER_MASTER_SRV/C_BusinessPartnerSupplierEdit",
      method: 'POST',
      headers: headers,
      qs: params2, // params set before
      json: true,
    }
    request(options, (error: any, response: any, body: any): any => {
      res.json(body);
    });
  }
});
```

Regards

Comment: Can you please explain this more?  Should I be sending "Cookie" header or "set-cookie" header?  What value should I be sending?  This site says Cookie is forbidden https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie

Comment: You should be sending "Cookie" header. But this example is done with node from server side. If you are calling it directly from browser (or postman), I think it automatically passes the "set-cookie" response to "cookie". You can check it with inspector. Wich is your case?

Comment: I'm using Node.  Turns out that XMLHttpRequest library blocks you from setting cookie because it says it's unsafe.  If I debug my way deep enough into it and manually delete "cookie" from the blacklisted headers, then update works.